# Python logging and rotating files

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I have a python program that is writing to a log file that is being rotated by Linux's logrotate command.  When this happens I need to signal my program to stop writing to the old file and start writing to the new one.  I can handle the signal but how do I tell python to write to the new file?

I am opening the file like this:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s:%(filename)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s',filename=log_file, level=logging.INFO)
```

and writing to it like this:

```
logging.log(level,"%s" % (msg))
```

The logging modules look very powerful but also overwhelming.  Thanks.

Answer (score 44):

Don't use `logging.basicConfig`, use `WatchedFileHandler`. Here's how to use it.

```python
import time
import logging
import logging.handlers

def log_setup():
    log_handler = logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler('my.log')
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s program_name [%(process)d]: %(message)s',
        '%b %d %H:%M:%S')
    formatter.converter = time.gmtime  # if you want UTC time
    log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.addHandler(log_handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

log_setup()
logging.info('Hello, World!')
import os
os.rename('my.log', 'my.log-old')
logging.info('Hello, New World!')
```

Comment: @TyHitzeman You mean RotatingFileHandler. RollingFileHandler is a Java thing.

Comment: This works great for the OP and other Unix users. FYI for Windows users: you can't use `WatchedFileHandler` according to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial). Checkout [RotatingFileHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) instead

Answer (score 33):

You may want to look at [WatchedFileHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#watchedfilehandler) to implement this, or as an alternative, implement log rotation with [RotatingFileHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler), both of which are in the [logging.handlers module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html).

Comment: Thanks!  If I need to I can go this route but currently the file is already being rotated outside of my code.  I was hoping there was a way to close the log and reopen it.

Comment: Ah ... WatchedFileHandler ... now I get it.

Comment: is there an option to have the rolled logs not currently being written to compressed (zipped)?  E.g the docs mention that `RotatingFileHandler ` would produce `app.log.1`, `app.log.2`, `...` but ideally these rolled logs would be optionally compressed to save space.

Answer (score 12):

```
from logging import handlers

handler = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename, when=LOG_ROTATE)

handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(log_format, datefmt="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"))

#LOG_ROTATE = midnight    
#set your log format
```

This should help you in handling rotating log

Answer (score 9):

Since rotation is already being done by `logrotate`, in your signal handler you should just call `logging.basicConfig(...)` again and that should reopen the log file.

Comment: `basicConfig` is a no-op if it's already been run.  To force it to reconfigure everything again, you have to set `logging.root.handlers = []` first.