# Python log rotation - After rotation, new log entries were written to the old rotated log file

Tags: python, logging, rotation, pyramid

I am writing a pyramid application, very simple one.

I've setup my logger in my pyramid `.ini` file like below, again, quite simple

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=timedRotatingFileHandler

[formatters]
keys=timedRotatingFormatter

[formatter_timedRotatingFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s
datefmt=%m-%d %H:%M

[handlers]
keys=timedRotatingFileHandler

[handler_timedRotatingFileHandler]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=timedRotatingFormatter
args=('/data/logs/mylog.log', 'midnight')
```

---

The strange thing is that the log files got rotated at midnight indeed, but since the rotation the new log entries for the new day are written into the yesterday's log file.

For example, say today is `2015-08-06`.

At `00:00` midnight, today's `mylog.log` is rotated and the name is changed to `mylog.log.20150806`, no problem so far.

But since then, the new log entries begin being written into `mylog.log.20150806` instead of into a new `mylog.log`.

Why is this?

Comment: What should happen is that the process gives up the file description (mylog.log.20150806 which is most likely renamed from mylog.log) and then starts to write to the new mylog.log file descriptor. Do you have multiple processes writing to the same log file? Sometimes you need to send a signal to UNIX processes to hint about the log file rotation.

Comment: Might be duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106795/python-logging-and-rotating-files

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa is the logrotation being handled by python packages or linux logrotate?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa in my case the rotation is handled by python logger, not by `linux logrotate`. so the other question doesn't apply

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing the same issue.