# Logs are lost due to log rotation of logging module

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I have written some devops related migration tool in python which runs for several hours (like 50-60 hours for each cluster migration activity). I used python's logging module in the tool to log relevant information. The log automatically rotates every 24 hours. As a result, the old log file gets zipped into .gz format and a new empty file (with same name) gets created. However, in the new file I cannot find any logs (that I thought would contain logs after the log rotation)

I tried googling this problem, but couldn't find relevant information. Would highly appreciate any help regarding this.

code snippet:

`import logging
LOG = logging.getLogger(name)`

def setup_logging(logfile, levelName):
    filename = logfile
    try:
        level = getattr(logging, levelName.upper())
    except:
        print 'Invalid loglevel:%s' % levelName
    logging.basicConfig(filename=filename,
                        level=level,
                        format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] [%(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)s()] %(message)s')

After setting up logging like that I use something like:

LOG.info('') / LOG.warning('')

Comment: We'd have to see some code to properly diagnosticate this!

Comment: Do you run multiple processes logging to the same file?

Comment: updated with code snippet. No, currently only one process per log file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I found a way to handle this kind of scenario by using WatchedFileHandler as suggested here:

[Python logging and rotating files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106795/python-logging-and-rotating-files)