# Python logging: is there any way to keep last n log files

Tags: python, logging

I'm new to python logging. I was wondering if there is a way to keep last n log files. This is my config:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    filename = "logs/log.log",
    filemode = "w",
    encoding = "utf-8",
    force = True,
    level = logging.INFO,
    format = "%(asctime)s %(levelname) -8s %(message)s",
    datefmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
)
```

I want to keep, let's say, 10 log files. When the 11st file is going to be generated, the 1st is deleted automatically.

Is there any way to do this directly or do I have to implement my own function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python logging and rotating files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106795/python-logging-and-rotating-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `backupCount` parameter as shown below.

### File Size Rotating Handler

```
log_formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s",
                                  datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")  # your logging format
log_handler = RotatingFileHandler("logss/log.log", mode="a", maxBytes=1024, backupCount=10, encoding="utf-8")
log_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)  # set logging level
logger.addHandler(log_handler)
```

The above log handler will keep the current log file (log.log) and up to 10 historical log files (since backupCount=10). Once the current log file reaches the specified size (maxBytes=1024 in this example), it will create a new log file and maintain only the last 10 log files, deleting the older ones.

### Time rotating handler

```
log_formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s", datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
log_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler("logs/log.log", when="M", interval=1, backupCount=10, encoding="utf-8")
log_handler.suffix = "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M.log"
log_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(log_handler)
```

The above log handler will keep the current log file (log.log) and up to 10 historical log files (since backupCount=10). It will rotate the file based on time interval here  `when="M"` (rotation happens every minute), `interval=1` (rotate every minute), and backupCount=10 (retain 10 log files). This when and inteval you can change it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement this yourself.
The implementation should be pretty straight forward:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import logging

max_files = 10
log_folder = "logs"

# if more than max_files *.log files are in log_folder, delete the oldest one
log_files = list(Path(log_folder).glob("*.log"))
if len(log_files) >= max_files:
    oldest_file = min(log_files, key=lambda f: f.stat().st_ctime)
    oldest_file.unlink()

# create new logging file with a unique name, e.g. a timestamp
time_str = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
logging.basicConfig(
    filename=f"{log_folder}/log_{time_str}.log",
)
```

Comment: This assumes that the program is stopped and run again, and doesn't do any rotation in the case where the program is meant to keep running. Also you don't need to spin up much of the rotation logic anyways, the logging module already implements stuff for that.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Why would one not be able to call this code in a function multiple times during runtime? And I did not understand the rotation logic remark, please elaborate.

Comment: So you're saying that one would wrap this in a function and then whenever they want to log, they'll check if they need to rotate if so call that function and then log? Yeah sounds like too much boilerplate to me. Check the duplicate target I've linked in the comments on the question, the logging module already has support for rotation you don't need to reinvent the wheel for that (Even if you wanted to do that you should be implementing a custom handler to do that instead of the way you do here).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thanks for the additional info! I was not aware of that functionality (and yes, my initial usecase was meant for stopping and restarting the program, i.e. to keep an archive)

Comment: @ChristianKarcher , that approach can be simplified with https://stackoverflow.com/a/44636428/17795398